# android studioでcolorを動的に変更する

Tags: android, android-studio

こんにちは、androidアプリを開発しているのですが、ボタンが押されたら、colors.xmlの中身かstyle.xmlの方で定義しているcolorPrimaryDarkとwindowBackgroundを同時に変更させたいのですが、どのような関数でsetできますか？もしくは、どのような方法で変更できますか？助力をください！（その時、見ているページだけではなく、全てのページを変えたいです。）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlで静的に定義している値は直接変えることが出来ません。この場合、変えたい色を別に定義しておき、それぞれを置き換える必要があります。
ご質問の内容から、恐らくはアプリへのカラーテーマの適用を行いたいのかなと思うのですが、そのような場合は例えば設定用のActivity等でユーザーの入力による設定値をプリファレンスなどに保存しておき、カラーテーマが必要な部分でプリファレンスから読み込んで一括変更すると楽です。
ユーザー設定カラーを取得するユーティリティクラスを作ると楽でしょう。
細かい部分は省略しますが、

context = Context
res = Resources
res_id = リソースID（ユーザー設定値でここをswitchして変えます）
として、

context.getDrawable(res_id);
または
res.getColor(res_id);

で取得できる値を返すメソッドを作り各要素に適用すると良いと思います。

追記：
リアルタイムで変化させたいということでしたので、その場合は上記の変更後リソースIDの取得と保存をカラー変更ボタンを押したタイミングにして、AndroidのプロパティアニメーションAPI（https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html）を適用すると良いでしょう。

複数のやり方がありますが、代表的には以下のようなものがあります。

１．直接カラーをアニメーションで変更する方法。（ボタンなどの場合は、アニメーションが終わったタイミングで背景をタップに反応するDrawableに変更する等の追加作業が必要な場合がある）

２．カラー変更後のビューの上に元の色のビューを重ねた状態に置き換え、アニメーションで元の色のビューの透過度を変化（徐々に透明にする）させて色を変更する方法。こちらでは、２つのビューのイメージが混ざりつつ変化します。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
おっしゃってくれた通りに、やろうと思って、調べたのですが、どうしても一回アクティビティを閉じて再起動して適応みたいな感じですよね？
私がやりたいのは、ボタンを押したら、徐々に色が変わって、それに適応されるような感じなのですが、できないのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答に追記しました。プロパティアニメーションの実装に関しては検索すると様々な方法が出てきますので割愛しますが、１番か２番の方法で徐々に色を変化させることが可能です。２番の亜種で、ビューを追加しないで全体を一旦徐々に透明にしてからカラーを変更し、徐々に遷移先の色に変化させる（段々不透明にする）という手もあります。この辺りは処理の重さと、目指しているものに応じて変えてください。

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。アニメーションでバックグランドは変えることができたのですが、どうしてもcolorPrimaryDark（時間やバッテリー残量がある上のバーです）を変えるために代入する場所が見つからないのですが、できればこちらもアニメーションで変えたいのでわかれば教えください。

Comment: 「時間やバッテリー残量がある上のバー」というのは、ステータスバーですね。getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color)等で変更出来ますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
バックグランドでgetWindow().decorView.setBackgroundColor() とかを使っていたのに気づけませんでした。助かりました！